# Output Matrix Content from Sibling

Tags: templating, matrix, gallery

I need to get Matrix field content from a entries sibling. Essentially, I have a block type called `gallery` within my project pages, and under the project content on each page, I have a section for Other Recent Projects. I'd like to be able to get the first image from the `gallery` block of the previous and next siblings and output it in this recent projects section. How can I do that?

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work (obviously, replace the `matrixField`, `assetsField` and `imageTransform` handles with real values):

```
{# Basic query parameters for your sibling entries #}
{% set siblingCriteria = craft.entries.section(entry.section.handle) %}

{# Creates an array with the next and previous entries, based on the basic query parameters #}
{% set siblingEntries = [entry.getPrev(siblingCriteria), entry.getNext(siblingCriteria)] %}

{# Loop through the next and previous entries
{% for siblingEntry in siblingEntries %}

    {% if siblingEntry %}{# This might be null, if there isn't a next or previous entry #}

        {# Get the first `gallery` block for the entry's Matrix field #}
        {% set galleryBlock = siblingEntry.matrixField.type('gallery').first() %}

        {# Get the first asset in the gallery block's Assets field #}
        {% set galleryImage = galleryBlock ? galleryBlock.assetsField.first() : null %}

        {# Render the image #}
        {% if galleryImage %}
            <a href="{{ siblingEntry.url }}">
                <img src="{{ galleryImage.getUrl('imageTransform') }}" />
            </a>
        {% endif %}

    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out on my own, based off this answer [here.](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4536/get-related-entries-from-matrix-field)

Here is the code I ended up using to achieve what I needed, used inside my matrix field.

```
{% if block.type == "featuredProjects" %}
  {% set relatedEntries = craft.entries.section('projects').relatedTo(block).limit(12) %}
  {% for entry in relatedEntries %}
  {% for asset in entry.mainHero %}
  <figure id="{{ entry.slug }}" class="featured-item position-relative">
    <a href="{{ entry.url }}">
      <img src="{{ asset.url }}">
      <figcaption class="project-info position-absolute gap-left-right pin-top-center">
        <h3 class="title">{{ entry.title }}</h3>
        <span>View Project</span>
      </figcaption> 
    </a>  
  </figure>
  {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
```